# java, my thread is terminated without any exception or throwable, why?

Tags: java, linux, multithreading, sockets, nio

I have a problem,my thread is terminated without any exception!!!

I have a thread for accepting socket (nio, but blocking-mode).that is works well, if socket get receiving requests by slow speed,but when receiving a lot of requests at a time ,the thread stops.

I changed a few options in linux, may be for this?

part of my code:

```
while(!Thread.interrupted() && !serverSocketChannel.socket().isClosed()){
        try
        {
            SocketChannel socketChannel = serverSocketChannel.accept();

            while (!socketChannel.finishConnect() && check < 50) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(20);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException ignored) {}
                check += 1;
            }
            check = 0;

            if(!socketChannel.finishConnect()){
                socketChannel.close();
                continue;
            }

            NioSocket socket = new NioSocket(server, socketChannel);

            if(acceptedSocketQueue.offer(socket))
                server.addSocket(socket);
            else
                socket.forceClose();
        }
        catch(Throwable e){
            Logger.log(SocketAccepter.class, e,"SocketAccepter, on accepting.");
        }
    }

Logger.log(SocketAccepter.class,"SocketAccepter ### interrupted.");
// I do not get here
```

changed options:

```
echo fs.file-max=500000 >> /etc/sysctl.conf
echo fs.nr_open=500000 >> /etc/sysctl.conf
echo fs.aio-max-nr=300000 >> /etc/sysctl.conf
echo fs.aio-nr=50000 >> /etc/sysctl.conf
echo net.ipv4.tcp_mem="2048 51200 725376" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
echo net.core.rmem_default=51200 >> /etc/sysctl.conf
echo net.core.rmem_max=725376 >> /etc/sysctl.conf
echo net.ipv4.tcp_rmem="2048 51200 725376" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
echo net.core.wmem_default=51200 >> /etc/sysctl.conf
echo net.core.wmem_max=725376 >> /etc/sysctl.conf
echo net.ipv4.tcp_wmem="2048 51200 725376" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
echo net.ipv4.tcp_syn_retries=4  >> /etc/sysctl.conf
echo net.ipv4.tcp_synack_retries=2  >> /etc/sysctl.conf
echo net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range=1024 65500  >> /etc/sysctl.conf
echo net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout=20  >> /etc/sysctl.conf
echo net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time=240  >> /etc/sysctl.conf
echo net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes=3  >> /etc/sysctl.conf
echo net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl=30  >> /etc/sysctl.conf
echo net.core.somaxconn=5000  >> /etc/sysctl.conf
echo net.core.netdev_max_backlog=5000  >> /etc/sysctl.conf
echo net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog=5000  >> /etc/sysctl.conf
echo net.core.rps_sock_flow_entries=32000  >> /etc/sysctl.conf
echo net.core.optmem_max=51100  >> /etc/sysctl.conf
echo net.ipv4.tcp_rfc1337=1  >> /etc/sysctl.conf
echo net.ipv4.tcp_max_orphans=2000  >> /etc/sysctl.conf
echo net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies=0  >> /etc/sysctl.conf
echo net.ipv4.tcp_adv_win_scale=2  >> /etc/sysctl.conf
```

please help me if you know.

---

Update:

I added a `Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler` to thread.
then I ran app by this command

`java - jar app.jar &>> log.txt`
and when thread stops I opened log file.

in log file I saw below line

```
Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "NioServer Accepter"
```

my new code was this

```
SocketChannel socketChannel = serverSocketChannel.accept();
 NioSocket socket = new NioSocket(server, socketChannel);
 acceptedSocketQueue.offer(socket);
```

I realized `serverSocketChannel.accept()` is causing this to happen, does anyone have a reason?

Comment: `catch (InterruptedException ignored) {} ` really?

Comment: that is for inside while{} and is not matter,this is for Thread.sleep()

Comment: You are completely misusing `finishConnect()` here. (1) You don't need to call it after `accept()` at all, only after `connect()`, (2) you don't need to call it in blocking mode, which the accepted socket channel is still in. Remove all this. Your code doesn't make sense.

Comment: Well, I surrendered. I saw the documents. You are right I will delete them. But why did I not receive any exceptions?

Comment: Carefree boy. I copied the code from a site in my program without care. The code was for non-blocking mode.I changed it a bit.very thanks for this.

Comment: I change my question. Is it possible a thread stops without throws a exception? I always thought that would make a exception.

Comment: I was surprised because I had no exceptions.Your time is important to me.Surely giving knowledge is also valuable to you Otherwise you would not have spent your time here.

Comment: I used visualVM and saw my accepter thread stops after than me sent 2000 requests to server (at a short time).

Comment: Mr. 'Marquis of Lorne'? Did you go Okay, thank you for your time. There is no one else. It is noon now, your place must be late.

Comment: Re, "that [ignoring an InterruptedException...] is not matter,this is for Thread.sleep()." I don't understand. Your outer loop _tests_ whether or not the thread has been interrupted. Do you care whether the thread is interrupted or do you not care? Why does it matter what the thread happens to be doing (awaiting `finishConnect()` or doing something else) at the exact moment when the interrupt is delivered?

Comment: Thanks  Solomon Slow, See, last line of my code is a logger that if 'InterruptedException' occur and break loop, program going to this logger ,so I must see log,but no. hence I think this exception was not occur.

Comment: Can you make a minimal reproducible example? It isn't clear what you're doing now, you were getting a NullPointerException?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem.

After a day of trial and error, the problem was finally solved by disabling a few options in linux.

I do not know exactly what these options do that caused that exception to be thrown! Someone knows?

But the options:

```
fs.file-max=500000
fs.nr_open=500000
fs.aio-max-nr=300000
fs.aio-nr=50000
```

I deleted them and the program worked properly.

Comment: None of that has anything do to with a `NullPointerException`. The only thing in your code that could do that would be `accept()` returning null, which means you must have the `ServerSocketChannel` in non-blocking mode, which means you should be using a `Selector` to tell you when to call `accept()`, instead of spin-looping.

Comment: I was also surprised. But by changing the options, my problem was solved.This exception is occurred inside the accept()  method. It was not the case that the output of the method was null.